# UINavigationController and "infinite" drill-down

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios7

Does anyone have and definitive information on how iOS handles a UINavigationController stack it the user is allow to keep drilling-down.  Will it actually start to free up memory by saving the state of the previous controllers?

This has been asked on here before, but the answers have been contradictory, so if anyone really knows how this is handled that'd be very useful.

If not, does anyone know of a subclass that will handle this?

Comment: What’s your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it depends on the implementation of your controllers.

When you keep pushing controller on to a navigation controller, eventually memory will get low. Controllers that you pushed on a navigation controller will not be released for you when memory gets low, though.

What happens is your controllers get a notification which is handled in your controllers' [`didReceiveMemoryWarning`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didReceiveMemoryWarning) method. There you can release all the objects used in your controller that are not necessary anymore or can be recreated when the controller is popped back.

> Memory is a critical resource in iOS, and view controllers provide built-in support for reducing their memory footprint at critical times. The UIViewController class provides some automatic handling of low-memory conditions through its didReceiveMemoryWarning method, which releases unneeded memory.
>
> Prior to iOS 6, when a low-memory warning occurred, the UIViewController class purged its views if it knew it could reload or recreate them again later. If this happens, it also calls the viewWillUnload and viewDidUnload methods to give your code a chance to relinquish ownership of any objects that are associated with your view hierarchy, including objects loaded from the nib file, objects created in your viewDidLoad method, and objects created lazily at runtime and added to the view hierarchy. On iOS 6, views are never purged and these methods are never called. If your view controller needs to perform specific tasks when memory is low, it should override the didReceiveMemoryWarning method.